# How to color the surface of the Box of 3D graphics

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

Is there any possibility to color the surface of the Box of a `Graphic3D[]`?

```
Show[Graphics3D[Sphere[]], ViewPoint -> Above, 
BoxStyle -> Directive[Large, Orange, Thick]]
```

I need to color the surface of the Box. (Like a wall).

Answer (score 3):

Not with BoxStyle:

```
Show[{Graphics3D[Sphere[], PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], 
      Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Green], Cuboid[{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 5}]}]}, 
    ViewPoint -> Above]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @phdstudent You should better use Polygon for that. See the help for Texture[]